# How to create wordpress plugin support page?

Tags: plugin-development

I want to add a support page to my plugin wordpress. My plugin is already developed. Now I want to allow users to contact me for any question. I want the support button to be next to the activate and Update buttons in the plugin add page.

Comment: Downvoted *I want to add a support page*. We all want certain things, but without putting in some effort, one will ever have what they want. What have you done to solve this issue, where is your research effort, where have you failed. No one is here to do your project for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`plugin_action_links_`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/plugin_action_links_(plugin_file_name)) filter for that task:

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'add_support_link_wpse_220726' );

function add_support_link_wpse_220726( $links ) {
   $links[] = '<a href="http://example.com/support/" target="_blank">Support</a>';
   return $links;
}
```

Note that you must also pass the plugin name (`plugin_basename(__FILE__)`) for it to work. That's why take into consideration from where you will call it.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this will do it...

```
add_filter('plugin_action_links', 'mycustom_plugin_action_links', 10, 2);
function mycustom_plugin_action_links($links, $file) {
    $thisplugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
    if ($file == $thisplugin) {
        $supportlink = "<a href='".admin_url('admin.php')."?page=mycustom-support'>Support</a>";
        array_unshift($links, $supportlink);
    }
    return $links;
}
```

Sounds like you might be needing `add_menu_page` also, so my answer assumes your link is to an admin page.

Comment: Doesn't have to be, there is no real reason the plugin links point only into the site, and not out of it. It is just a lousy place for that in terms of UX, but it is possible.

Comment: I know this, but maybe you can reread first sentence of the question again, I was trying to answer the question asked.

Comment: yeh, the question sucks and confusing